# Easiest way to embed alert pop-ups on each page of existing Asp.Net MVC (RazorView) application

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

We have an existing ASP.NET MVC 4 application written using RazorView. The requirement is to show information messages as pop-ups on each page.

Information might be available in an ajax call to a service(meta data)/ after some operation on form submit.

We would like to make minimal changes to the existing app logic.
Please suggest the best way to implement this functionality.

For messages that would be available on pageLoad, I planned to use ActionFilters.
(Set ViewBag with the script and embed the same in layout page)

However, I do not have a clue if a generic approach can be applied for ajax calls and postback (form submit).

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I did not get much help, here is the approach which was followed:

1.Use filter/ override OnResultExecuting event in MyBaseController to add message to ViewBag and in Layout page embed a script block when ViewBag.Message is not empty. This will take care of displaying message on page load.

2.For messages that would be available only after the completion of ajax requests, we can set the message in a session variable and place another request to query this value. Usage of cookies is not acceptable and we do not have concurrent ajax requests on the page.
Hence, even if there is an extra call, code changes are minimal and suits our requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You think right to my mind. In base controller, one can define your messages

```
public class YourBaseController : Controller
{
      protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
      {
         ViewBag.Message  = "This will go to dialog in view";
      }
}
```

And in `_Layout` you can show vale of ViewBag in dialog. You can also take message values from config file to change your code less.

```
ViewBag.Message  = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["This will go to dialog in view"];
```

Comment: But my requirement is not so straight forward. Some messages might be available based on business scenario.. on some user scenario like --- you cannot edit data until next 2 hrs--- message might be made available through a web-service along with a table of content. Now, I would like to show alerts after getting the info via Json Result in an ajax call. Please note that there is no provision to hold this message in the view-Model. I would like to know if I can pass this extra information as meta data and if there is a generic way to handle this scenario.